# Show stack of images one on top of the other in iOS

Tags: ios, image, stack, frame, swipe

I'm trying to develop a simple app that shows a stack of images: each image on top of the other. And when you swipe or click a button, the first image will disappear and the image below it will have the same size as the one that was on the top (as in the image below, but without the rotation effect)

[image]

I've tried to fetch the images and create the frame of the images at each for loop iteration:

```
UIImageView*picture = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40+10*i, 101-10*i, 240-20*i, 200)];
                        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                        picture.image = image;
                        [dView addSubview:picture];
```

and it worked. But I still can't find how to make the second image in the same size as the one that was on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
CGrect nextImageFrame = nextImage.frame;
nextImageFrame.size.width = 240;
nextImageFrame.size.height = 200;
nextImage.frame = nextImageFrame;
```

assuming that `nextImage` is the image you want to show next